# Unity: Unity resources location in .apk file compiled for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on Unity and I have some custom fonts which I have imported in the Assets/Resources/Fonts folder. I am able to use these fonts well.

I want to see where these font or any resource is present in apk which is created when you compile Unity project for android. I tried that and there are no .ttf files or any other resource file. There are lot of binary files in assets\bin\Data folder. I think unity somehow converts all my resources into binary and packages it to apk.

I want to know

1. Does unity create binary files from resource files using some algorithm?If No, then where are the resources located?
2. If yes, is there some documentation on how unity does that? Is there some way to find those resources from those binary files?